# Unable to terminate a job without opening it

Tags: shell, task

I run the following code unsuccessfully

```
sudo killall %4
```

where %4 is my Vim session.

How can you terminate a job without foregrounding it?

Comment: Do you mean, "how do you terminate a job without foregrounding it"?

Comment: @Charles: I mean exactly what you say. I clarified the question such that it is easier to find it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want "kill" instead of "killall".  I tested under tcsh like this:

```
home% cat
^Z
Suspended
home% kill %1
home% 
[1]    Terminated                    cat
```

Furthermore, I doubt this would work with sudo because sudo would invoke a new shell, wouldn't it?  And in that shell, %4 would not be defined.

```
home% cat
^Z
Suspended
home% sudo kill %1
Password:
kill: illegal process id: %1
```

If you really need to sudo, you can try this:

```
home% jobs -l
[1] + 26318 Suspended cat
home% sudo kill 26318
```

Comment: good point on the sudo. without using sudo -, you should still inherit some of the shell environment though... hmm...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used initially kill, but it did not work for my Vim process. I therefore use killall with sudo in my code example to make my command my powerful. 

It is now obvious for me that sudo does not make the command more powerful, and that killall does not make the command kill more powerful, neither.

Answer (score 3):

Try `kill %4` instead. The unix shell uses %x as variables for currently running processes. To see the processes you can use with the %x syntax, use `jobs`. Killall is a wrapper around "kill" that is basically the equivalent of `ps -aux | grep  | cut -f2 -d " " | xargs kill' or the like if you're a shell junky.

No, sorry, that shell command won't quite work, but it does illustrate how killall works =p. It simply kills every process it can that matches the string you provide.

Also, try `man kill' to learn more about kill. Particularly, kill -9 you may find useful. It's sorta the equivalent of 'force quit'.

Comment: @Erik: Thank you for your explanation about how killall works. It seems that however: killall does NOT include kill mathematically: see Chris' code example.